# Django manual file upload to s3 times out - 502

Tags: python, django, image, file-io, amazon-s3

I have a script in the admin panel of our site that allows us to upload images, crop them and save them. On save, the original image is cropped and uploaded. We use `cuddlybuddly.storage.s3.S3Storage` for our storages backend.

Here's the chunk that uploads the image:

```
    name, contents = self.crop_image(x, y, w, h, (220, 142), 'default_filter')
    if name is not None and contents is not None:
        self.default_filter_image.save(
                    name,
                    ContentFile(contents.getvalue()), save=False
            )
```

Cropping the image takes almost no time, the 502 happens when it tries to call the `self.default_filter_image.save()` bit. The images we are uploading are less than 100k (tiny).

Here's the `crop_image` function in case something in there is causing problems.

```
def crop_image(self, x, y, w, h, finished_size, img_prop):
    """
    Returns a cropped version of an image based on some size settings that are passed in. Used to
    create all the sizes and can be used for any size crop.
    """
    original = None

    if self.original_image:
        self.original_image.seek(0)
        original = Image.open(self.original_image)

    if original is not None and x is not None and y is not None \
                    and w is not None and h is not None:

        orig = original.copy()

        cropped = orig.crop(
                # left, upper, right, lower
                (x, y, (x + w), (y + h))
        )

        cropped = cropped.resize(finished_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        tmp = Image.new('RGB', cropped.size)
        tmp.paste(cropped, (0, 0))
        cropped = tmp

        contents = StringIO()
        cropped.save(contents, format='jpeg', quality=90)
        contents.seek(0)
        filename = '%s_%s.jpg' % (str(uuid.uuid4()), img_prop)

        return (filename, contents)

    return (None, None)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can even debug this?

Comment: I have the same/similar problem.  My AWS server was t1.micro and everything works fine.  When I change the type to m3.medium this stops working and gives me 502.  Other read/write functions are fine (I'm using RDS too).  When I revert the m3.medium to t1.micro, the save works again.  Moreover, I have a local VM on VirtualBox and configure to use the S3 and RDS as well.  The connection is slow yet it works fine too.  It just seems m3.medium and s3 cannot get well along.  I'm going to ask AWS about this.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Actually, I eventually tracked it down to one of the apps that was out of date. It's been a little while since I thought about it, but I believe it was an out of date API it was trying to use. I think it was CuddlyBuddly, but can't say for absolute certain. Let me know if you discover something similar and I will post it as the answer.

Comment: I tried to run `pip install boto --update` on the server to see if it is outdated but it said it's most updated.  Also did the same for `django-storages`.  AWS Support didn't help much neither.  At the end, I started a new VM using Vagrant with m3.medium as instance type.  The new instance works perfectly.  So, I gave up on solving why the previous instance (built in end of Oct, less than 2 months ago) wouldn't work.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I went back in my commits and found that I had abandoned cuddlybuddly in favor of django-storages and the s3Boto configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CuddlyBuddly is out of date and queries for the entire list of files in the bucket every time it wants to post one, which eventually slows down and stops working entirely. The django-storages app using s3Boto is more up to date and works great.

https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html